# Extracting specific data from a large amount of data in a single "cell" of a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Long time reader first time questioner...

I'm attempting to use Drupal to create a set of variables, not the issue, it's all in place to set them and simple for the future operator to edit.

I then need to grab these values in php, still on the site but outside of Drupal to some extent. Again, although I'm a bit of a lightweight on PHP, I can get what I need. However drupal stores the data all in one "cell" (apologies, I've searched for what I'm after but I think my vocabulary is lacking to get the right result!). Here's an example of how it is stored:

> a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"value";s:2:"38";s:5:"label";s:11:"Cost Per
>   M2";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:3:{s:5:"value";s:1:"7";s:5:"label";s:13:"Arch
>   Top
>   Cost";s:6:"weight";s:1:"1";}i:2;a:3:{s:5:"value";s:1:"5";s:5:"label";s:13:"Flat
>   Top Cost";s:6:"weight";s:1:"2";}}

So I can happily return the whole contents as above, but I haven't the slightest how to refine it down to a specific reference. I can work out the data is contained between certain sets of brackets so, one ref is:

```
{s:5:"value";s:2:"38";s:5:"label";s:11:"Cost Per M2";s:6:"weight";s:1:"0";}
```

What I really need is the "38" in the example, as this is a cost that a 2nd system uses a number of to calculate a final cost.

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is serialised (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). What you want to do is unserialize it (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). So it would be:

```
$deserializedValues = unserialize($values).
```

After that you can call the variables by doing:

```
$deserializedValues['value'] (if an array)

$deserializedValues->value (if an object)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, it was more of a vocab issue, I didn't know it was described as serialised. I suspect I can figure it out now.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drupal returns JSON. The cleanest way to handle this would be to use PHP's json_decode() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I made the same mistake mate... it's not JSON after all..it's serialized PHP values.. notice the S:5:"value"... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php :(

Comment: You're right, my mistake, the values are serialized - serialize/unserialize is what you'll need here, as mentioned above